# Running integration testing for Flutter on Azure Devops pipeline for UI automation testing

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, flutter-test

I would like to run automated UI testing using flutter driver on Azure Devops Pipelines and I'm using [Flutter Tasks by Alois Daniel](https://github.com/aloisdeniel/vsts-flutter-tasks%20%20https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aloisdeniel.flutter). There is no flutter driver support currenly on the azure flutter tasks plugin. We are looking for tasks where it would start up the simulators for Android and iOS while running flutter driver tests. We are running a vm-image for macos-latest in azure devops pipeline yml file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To achieve what i wanted to do, i instead created a file with the below code and added script capability pushed it to the project

```
# DO NOT RUN ON YOUR LOCAL MACHINE
echo "install xcode in command line"
xcode-select --install
echo "install home brew"
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
echo "install flutter using brew"
brew install --cask flutter
echo "starting up apple emulator"
flutter emulators --launch <apple_ios_simulator/android emulator>
echo "awaiting for emualator to load"
sleep 5
echo "starting integration tests"
flutter drive --target=test_driver/<yourtestfile>.dart
```

call this in your azure-pipeline yml as a bash script via drag and drop from the side-panel of your dev ops. Run it and you will see it work.
Some limitations are when it comes to system dialog boxes on the android/ios emulators which requires user permission, you can follow it [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/12561).
For iOS there is a tool called [AppleSimulatorUtils](https://github.com/wix/AppleSimulatorUtils)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no such build-in extension to achieve what you need.

As an alternative , you could create your own extension, suggest you check the following articles to do that:

- [Add a build or release task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-build-task?view=azure-devops)
- [Reference for integrating custom build tasks into extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/integrate-build-task?view=azure-devops)
- [How To Build An Azure Custom Build/Release Task](https://blog.ipswitch.com/how-to-build-an-azure-custom-build/release-task)
- [azure-pipelines-tasks samples](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/tree/master/Tasks)